# Apache 2.4 reload succeeds but restart fails when using SSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, mod-ssl, apache-2.4

On Apache 2.4, **reload** succeeds but **restart** fails when using SSL.  Or to say it another way, the SSL configuration directives appear to work perfectly when doing a service **reload** but not a service **restart**.

The following sequence of commands:

```
service apache2 start
a2ensite secure.example.com
service apache2 reload
```

Allows me to browse https://secure.example.com without any errors, but a subsequent `service apache2 restart` with no interim changes to any configuration files causes apache2 to fail to start, with the message:

```
The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

I can then use:

```
a2dissite secure.example.com
service apache2 start
a2ensite secure.example.com
service apache2 reload
```

And again access https://secure.example.com.  The situation seems to be related to the use of SSL, as I can comment out the SSL configuration bits from secure.example.com and do an Apache restart without any issues.

Ubuntu 13.10, Linux 3.0.20-xenU, Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu), OpenSSL/1.0.1e

Comment: The directives that trigger the restart failure are `SSLCertificateChainFile `, `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile`, `SSLEngine`.

Comment: Is that the only SSL listener?  Are there any errors in the Apache error log on the failed startups?

Comment: Results are identical whether testing with one or several SSL listeners.

Comment: I am seeing log messages from Apache, but as best I can tell there are no helpful errors or warnings in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/apache2/errors.log`, or `/var/log/apache2/secure.example.com/errors.log`.